# XMLHttpRequest() is not working in Firefox.

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest

I don't know why XMLHttpRequest() is not working in Firefox. Works in Chrome and IE.
This code is about change the language of my website.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#idioma_ingles").click(function(){
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "?idioma=2", true);
xmlhttp.send();
  location.reload();

});

$("#idioma_espanol").click(function(){
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "?idioma=1", true);
xmlhttp.send();
  location.reload();

  });

 });

 </script>
```

Comment: can it be that your page reloads before the request gets sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either do it like this so the page get reloaded after the request is done, or just skip the ajax and use a regular link

```
$.get("?idioma=1", function() {
 location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reloading the page (causing the request to be canceled) immediately after you call `send()`.

You could wait for the response before calling `reload()` but it would b be better to simply not use Ajax for this: there's no point. Just use a regular link to `?idioma=whatever`.